PHPで作成した問い合わせフォームをGメールに送るにはどうすればよろしいでしょうか？
PHPで作成した問い合わせフォームからメールが送信できない
上記にあるコードを利用させて頂いて、私のGメールのアドレスにメールを送ろうとしているのですが、
メールが送られません。
問い合わせ内容を送信すると「hello」とは出力されるのですが、肝心の問い合わせ内容がGメールに来ません。
どのようにすればよろしいでしょうか？
htmlのコード
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="contact2.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-content pt-5">
        <div class="form-left ">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name
                " placeholder="名前">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mt-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email
                " placeholder="メールアドレス">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-right">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="message
                " placeholder="お問い合わせ" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="上記の内容で送信する" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit text-center" id="button"></p>
</form>

PHPのコード
<?php
echo 'hello';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $emailFrom = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $mailTo = "自分のメールアドレス@gmail.com";
    $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
    $txt ="You have received an e-mail from " .$name.".\n\n".$message;

    mail($mailTo, $txt , $headers);
    header("location: contact2.php?mailsend");        
}



補足：MAMPを使っております。
Xサーバーというものは使っておりません。Dockerはインストールしておりません。

PHPのSMTPサーバー設定は確認されましたでしょうか?

重複候補: PHPでgmailにメール送信をしたいが送ることが出来ない

ご返信あリがとうございます。SMTPのポート番号を25から587に変えたのですが、うまくいきません。MAMPを再起動しました。

https://www.sejuku.net/blog/24658

teratail で解決済みのようです。

メールが送れないのはPHPのコードの問題ではなく、PHPが動作する環境の問題です。
Windows以外(Mac含む)の環境では、PHPのmail関数(及びmb_send_mail関数)はsendmailコマンドを使用します。sendmailコマンドはSendmailというソフトウェアに付属するコマンドラインベースのメール送信クライアントですが、PostfixやEximやmsmtpなどが提供するsendmail互換のコマンドの場合もあります。mail関数はsendmailコマンドをそのまま使用するため、sendmailコマンド(または互換性のあるコマンド)自体がメールを送信できるように設定されている必要があります。
Macの場合、標準でPostfixがインストールされており、sendmailコマンドも用意されています。このPostfixのデフォルト状態では、外部にメールを送信することはできません。外部にメールを送信できるようPostfixを正しく設定して、sendamilコマンドでメールを送信できる状態にできれば、PHPのmail関数でもメールを送信できるようになります。
ということで、調べるべき事は、PHPの事では無く、Mac標準のPostfixについているsendmailコマンドを使ってメールを送るためにはどうすれば良いかです。調べてもわからないときは「Macのsendmailコマンドでgmailにメールを送りたい」という内容で質問してみてください。(検証できるMacが今手元にないので、私は回答できませんが。)

以下、蛇足です。

php.iniでSMTPやsmtp_portを設定すれば良いという情報がありますが、その設定はWindowsでのみ有効です。Macでは完全に無視されます。何をどう変更しても、意味がありません。

PHPのmail関数でメールを送れるようにするのは、PHPのコードを書く人の責任では無く、PHPの環境を用意する人の責任です。PHPでプログラムを作るための知識(いわゆるプログラミング)では無く、PHPが動作する環境を作るための知識(いわゆるインフラ)が必要です。PHPの学習を目的とする場合は、余計な知識かも知れません。

メール送信をサポートしているレンタルサーバーの場合、PHPのmail関数でメールを送れるようになっています。環境の用意するのが難しいというのであれば、レンタルサーバーを借りるのも一つの手です。(1日あたりの送信数に制限はありますが、通常運用で上限になることは希です。)

mail関数以外にもメールを送信できるPHPのライブラリ(PHPMailer等)があります。それらであれば、PHPのコードだけでどのようにしてメールを送信するのかを指定できるので、動作しているPHPの環境に関わらず、メール送信できることがあります。(その方法がいいのかどうかは、場合によります。)



インフラ整備の中には DKIM とか DMARC とか SPF とかの整備も含んでいるので、今どきは動作テストとか勉強のために TheInternet 上でメール使うってのは難しいっスね。
